# Setup publish to folder using VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, continuous-delivery, web-publishing, one-click-web-publishing

I was using `publish to folder` option through Visual Studio by right-clicking on the project -> publish -> publish to folder. Result was always ready-to-copy project with applied transformations.
I wanted to automate this process using VSTS and have setup build on VSTS.
I used next steps:
- `NuGet restore`
- `Build solution`
- `Publish Build Artifacts` to `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)`
- `Windows machine file copy` from `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)` to remote machine using `admin login` and `password`

And finally I'm getting zip package on remote machine with complicated folder structure without applied transformations inside at all.
What is wrong? How I can setup same "publish to folder" as in Visual Studio but using VSTS?

Comment: Do you solve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add below Target to your .csproj to enable transforming config files

```
<Target Name="TransformConfigFiles" AfterTargets="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(TransformConfigFiles)'=='true'">
<ItemGroup>
  <DeleteAfterBuild Include="$(WebProjectOutputDir)\Web.*.config" />
</ItemGroup>
<TransformXml Source="Web.config" Transform="$(ProjectConfigTransformFileName)" Destination="$(WebProjectOutputDir)\Web.config" />
<Delete Files="@(DeleteAfterBuild)" /></Target>
```

In your build solution step add the following build arguments "/p:TransformConfigFiles=true" will make the config transformation using the above added target to .csproj

```
/p:TransformConfigFiles=true /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:OutDir="$(build.stagingDirectory)"
```

[image]

Then you can use a publish step to publish your $(build.stagingDirectory) contents. You can use $(build.stagingDirectory)_PublishedWebsites as path to publish if you only need the website output.

[image]

This will allow you to get the ms deploy package as well as xcopy deploy published website files.

[image]

You can use copy files task before the publish task to copy any additional files if you have any to  $(build.stagingDirectory) and get them published as build artifacts.

Use [VSTS release management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/release/what-is-release-management) with [deployment groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/release/deployment-groups/) to deploy your application to target server. You can use [IIS deploy task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-rm.iiswebapp) to deploy to IIS using ms deploy package. If you are using web deploy package you can use a [parameters.xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/web-deployment-in-the-enterprise/configuring-parameters-for-web-package-deployment) in your web app to get the web config parameters assigned to .setparameters.xml so that you can change values in the deployment time using IIS deployment task.

Comment: Thanks! Just checked _PublishedWebsites folder and there is a Web.config file without applied transformations. How can I force to transform?

Comment: @Tim I have added a target that should be added to your web project .csproj file to enable transform configuration, to the answer, assuming that this is ASP.NET MVC project

Comment: This may have solved OP problem, but this way '/p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true' you end up with a '.zip' instead of the default behaviour of VS publish to folder, which is achieved with @starian chen-MSFT answer. That answer should be the one marked as resolved, given it actually answers OP questions.

Answer (score 6):

You are publishing web application through File System method, it is based on the specified **configuration** (e.g. Debug, Release) to transform web.config. So you need to check which configuration you specified in build solution task (e.g. Visual Studio Build task)

Simple tasks:

1. NuGet Tool Installer task
2. NuGet restore task
3. Visual Studio Build task (MSBuild Arguments: `/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:publishUrl="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\" /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish`; Platform: `$(BuildPlatform)`; Configuration: `$(BuildConfiguration)`) Note: **BuildPlatform** and **BuildConfiguration** are build variables. It will publish web app to artifacts directory ([agent working folder]/1/a)
4. Publish Build Artifacts (Path to publish: **$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)**)

Comment: This gives the expected output of a VS publish to folder, with all it's contents unzipped, unlike @ChamindaC approach. It worked for me, and "saved my life" because I needed the unzipped output in next steps. Thanks.

Comment: I was missing the /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish, I needed both that and /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem for the files to be copied